# Django - comparison in if condition in template according to type of data

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In the `{% if %}` part, I want to compare a number in string form with another. I tried `slice` filter but it does not work. I have to compare a string because I guess **all numbers passed to template are interpreted as string in django**, and no way to convert string to number in template.

I am getting the partition info and send it to template, in a `<table>`. If a partition's used percentage is above 90%, the percentage should be in red.

Because there are more than one partition in the machine, so the conditional style of rows are independent, so it is better to decide when rendering, not in the view.

The percentage comes as integer (`89`), not in decimal(`0.7`). If it is decimal, I can use `{% if '0.9' in value %}`, but it is not the case.

I have my template like this: (`part.0` to `part.4` are other data about partitions)

```
<tbody>
    {% for part in partitions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{part.0}}</td> <td>{{part.1}}</td> <td>{{part.2}} GB </td> <td>{{part.3}} GB </td> <td>{{part.4}} GB </td> 
        {% if part.5|slice:"0:1" == "8" or part.5|slice:"0:1" == "9" %}
        <td><font color="red">{{part.5}}%</font></td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{part.5}}%</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

----------------------EDIT 1----------------------------

`part` is a list with data obtained from `psutil.disk_partitions('some_partition')` and `psutil.disk_usage("some_mountpoint")`, appending `sdiskpart.device`, `sdiskpart,mountpoint`, `sdickusage.total`, `sdiskusage.free`, `sdiskusage.free`, `sdiskusage.percent`. It is like:

```
['/dev/sda1', '/boot',  'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', '20.9']
```

----------------------EDIT 1----------------------------

Now, it does not complain, but does not turn red neither when the data matches the condition.

What can I do to accomplish my goal?

PS:

In the documentation, I see this frase:

> Filters
>   You can also use filters in the if expression. For example:
>
> ```
> {% if messages|length >= 100 %}
>     You have lots of messages today!
> {% endif %}
> ```

But, it mentions no other filters which are accepted. So, are filters like `slice`, or other things, are permitted? It seems not.

I have seen other posts about using filters in template, but they don't mention using it in `if`, but are like `{{ str.slice }}`.

Comment: Slicing in templates works the same as in Python; a slice of `0:1` gives a list, it cannot ever equal an integer.

Comment: But, it gives a list? I doubt.... `>>> '18.9'[0:1]   '1'`.

Comment: I mean, I want to slice a string.

Comment: Can you show what `part` actually looks like?

Comment: please tell us what you want to do so we can give you other methods

Comment: OK, OP edited with "edit 1". Thanks for all

Comment: If the last element `20.9` is of type int, does django template interpret it as string? If not I can compare it with `90`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer.

If I pass `(float) '90.7'` into the list, Django template can compare it with `90`. Amazing. Before I passed it in as string.

So the list should be like:

```
['/dev/sda1', '/boot',  'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 20.9] 
# last element is a float
```

And such comparison stands in the template:

```
{% if part.5 > 90.0 %}
...
{% endif %}
```